# Change 'Access Modifier' of existing resources

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I have got an existing Resources file with a lot of strings. During creation I've set the Access Modifier to `Internal`.

How I can change Access Modifier to `No code  generation` for an existing resource file?

Answer (score 1):

Double click the resource file to open it. At the top, choose `No code generation`

[image: Visual Studio 2013 screenshot]

If double-clicking does not work, you have set a different editor as the default editor. In this case, right-click the RESX file and select `Open with ...` and then `Managed Resource Editor`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to No Code generation even after you changed to iternal as shown in below figure select from the dropdown list after double clicking on the resource file

[image]